# Detect Users Keyboard Format on a Virtual Mac Machine

Tags: macos, layout, keyboard, virtual-machine, keyboard-layout

So we have a virtual Mac machine set up. It currently has a default US keyboard set up. If a user from (say) Germany logs into the Virtual Machine, I need to run a script on the virtual machine that finds out the Keyboard layout of the user logging in, and then accordingly changes the Keyboard layout on the Mac.

I plan on using AppleScripts UI Scripting to change the actual layout of the Virtual Machine. But how do I go about detecting the keyboard attached on a real device from a virtual machine ?

Example :: Say you login from Germany to my virtual Mac. In that case, your German keyboard has Y & Z interchanged. But, my virtual machine has the normal QWERTY format. So when you type Y, it actually types in Z, and vice versa. So when you connect to my virtual Mac, I need to identify you are using a German keyboard, and change the keyboard set up on my virtual machine to your format accordingly.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want. Do you want to set the set the keyboard (input method) of the guest machine to the keyboard of the host machine? Is the host machine a Mac or something else? Why did you decide it has to be AppleScript? I could imagine a method, but it involves much more than a simple script.

Comment: Yes. Say you login from Germany to my virtual machine(which in this case is a Mac). In that case, your keyboard has Y & Z interchanged. But, my virtual machine has the normal QWERTY format. So when you type Y, it actually types in Z, and vice versa. So when you connect to my virtual Mac, I need to identify you are using a German keyboard, and change the keyboard set up on my virtual machine to your format accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you give the user access to the keyboard menu in the top-right of your screen?
I understand that you don't want to know the input method of the host machine but the input method of the remote user's machine. I don't think this is possible without the user installing and activating some software. Making this software will be a task for a programmer. I'm quite sure that it will be easier for the user to just choose the right input method from the Keyboard menu.

Comment: I wanted that part to be transparent, and automatically do the switch in the keyboard input method for the user. I won't close this question yet, incase anyone else can come up with a method to do this.

Comment: Just some ideas. Set up an account with a desktop picture showing the most important info, such as where to click to change the keyboard (use arrows). Or put an AppleScript applet or an alias to a text document into the startup folder, to display additional information. Or make a presentation with the basics, e.g. in a standalone PowerPoint presentation, a HyperStudio application, or just some slides saved as a QT movie, and display this presentation automatically when the user logs in on the account.
I agree btw, don't close this yet. Maybe someone has a better idea.